# Nginx container doesn’t copy files to my host

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to copy a set of files (etc/nginx/*) from Nginx container to myhost (./nginx) but don't work.
Every time I run my docker-compose, the folder on the host (/ usr / development / nginx) is empty.
How can I do this?

**Environment**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

**Docker Compose**

```
docker-compose version 1.25.5, build 8a1c60f6
```

**Docker**

```
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

    services:
      nginx:
        container_name: 'nginx'
        hostname: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: /bin/sh -c "while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
        volumes:
          - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
          - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
          - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        networks:
          - docker-network
      portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer
        container_name: portainer
        hostname: portainer
        ports:
         - 9000:9000
        volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
         - ./portainer/data:/data
        networks:
          - docker-network

      certbot:
        container_name: 'certbot'
        hostname: certbot
        image: certbot/certbot
        volumes:
          - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
          - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
        restart: unless-stopped
        entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;"
        depends_on:
          - nginx
        networks:
          - docker-network
    networks:
      docker-network:
        name: docker-network
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: can you use full reference path of (/usr/development/nginx).
  - /usr/development/nginx:/etc/nginx and check

Comment: That `volumes:` directive tells Docker to take the (empty) host directory and hide any content in the image with it.  It does not copy content out at startup time.